# Change min-height depending on my div height

Tags: jquery, css, resize

So i have a slideshow block(its responsive) and i have set `min-height: 315px` for this block, i really need it, but when i resize window i need to reduce `min-height` smoothly, right now i wrote jQuery code, so its working, but its ugly tbh.

```
function minHeightBehavior(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        element = $('#block-views-home-page-slider-block');
        sliderHeight = $('.views-field-slider').height();
        element.css('min-height', '315px');
        if (width >= 769 && width < 960) {
            console.log(sliderHeight);
            element.css('min-height', sliderHeight +'px');

        }

    }
```

right now blocks below the slider, is jumping up, its because **for example** when window `screen width` is 900, `element height` is 300 and if `screen width` is 899, `element height` is 300 too. After that if `screen width` is 898, `element height` is 299, etc.
Maybe there is a better solution out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.animate` method.

(*and start using `var` for local variables*)

```
function minHeightBehavior(width) {
        var width = parseInt(width),
            element = $('#block-views-home-page-slider-block'),
            sliderHeight = $('.views-field-slider').height(),
            minHeight = 315;

        if (width >= 769 && width < 960) {
            minHeight = sliderHeight;
        }

        element.animate({height: minHeight + 'px'}, 500, function(){
           $(this).css({'min-height': minHeight + 'px', 'height':'auto'});
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a way to set the min-height as a percentage? Instead of using pixels.

Comment: yep :< no way, i cant set it too any percentage